# How to calculate the vector from two points in 3d with python

Tags: python, math

I am trying to generate a vector between the origin (0,0,0) to a specific point. How do I turn the math into code?

Edit:

Sorry about the unclarity.

Let's say that I have point o (0,0,0) and point p (3,6,8) that sit in a 3d coordinate system.

How can I calculate the vector from point o in the direction of point p?

Comment: By writing a formula...

Comment: The question as it is is too broad. Please show some contex, e.g. in the shape of a  program which defines the point data in a suitable data structure and e.g. is able to output the result (even if it is hard coded to the obviously wrong (1;2;3)).

Comment: At least show the math. A vector from the origin to any point in 3D can be represented by 3 coordinates.

Comment: Just what do you mean by "point" and "vector" in python? There is no standard meaning for those--there are multiple implementations. Please show example input, expected output, and some of your own attempts at a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like others I am a bit unclear. From what I understand all you want is a vector that will take you from one point to another point. This is just basic vector addition and is very simple. I made so it works for any dimension not just the third.

```
def multiDimenDist(point1,point2):
   #find the difference between the two points, its really the same as below
   deltaVals = [point2[dimension]-point1[dimension] for dimension in range(len(point1))]
   runningSquared = 0
   #because the pythagarom theorm works for any dimension we can just use that
   for coOrd in deltaVals:
       runningSquared += coOrd**2
   return runningSquared**(1/2)
def findVec(point1,point2,unitSphere = False):
  #setting unitSphere to True will make the vector scaled down to a sphere with a radius one, instead of it's orginal length
  finalVector = [0 for coOrd in point1]
  for dimension, coOrd in enumerate(point1):
      #finding total differnce for that co-ordinate(x,y,z...)
      deltaCoOrd = point2[dimension]-coOrd
      #adding total difference
      finalVector[dimension] = deltaCoOrd
  if unitSphere:
      totalDist = multiDimenDist(point1,point2)
      unitVector =[]
      for dimen in finalVector:
          unitVector.append( dimen/totalDist)
      return unitVector
  else:
      return finalVector
```

EDIT, forgot to include usage:

```
 vector = findVec([0,0,0],[3,6,8])# you can also set unitCircle to True
 >>[3,6,8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear but here is an example how to plot some 3D vectors

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

vectors=np.array( [ [0,0,1,1,-2,0], [0,0,2,1,1,0],[0,0,3,2,1,0],[0,0,4,0.5,0.7,0]]) 
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
for vector in vectors:
    v = np.array([vector[3],vector[4],vector[5]])
    vlength=np.linalg.norm(v)
    ax.quiver(vector[0],vector[1],vector[2],vector[3],vector[4],vector[5],
              pivot='tail',length=vlength,arrow_length_ratio=0.3/vlength)
ax.set_xlim([-4,4])
ax.set_ylim([-4,4])
ax.set_zlim([0,4])
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
plt.show()
```

[image]